# Natural transformations and small categories

Tags: category-theory

If $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are small categories (i.e. objects are sets, not proper classes) and $F,G:\mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ are both (contra/co)variant functors, then the the 'collection' of natural transformations $Nat(F,G)$ is also a set.

Say we now have arbitary categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$, with functors $S,T$ such that $S,T:\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$. Then it seems logical that $Nat(S,T)$ may be a proper class, and not a set.

Can anyone provide any examples?

Moreover (this is a bit more philosophical) - are such examples pathological, or do non-small categories arise naturally, outside of say, just studying higher category theory?

I am guessing in something like higher homotopy theory, one could possibly get in trouble?

This [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130/whats-so-special-with-small-categories) seems somewhat related

Comment: "objects are sets, not proper classes" is not what "small category" means. It means the class of all objects is a set, not that each object is one.

Comment: @Alon - thank you for that. Is that why the category of sets is not a small category - there is no collection of all sets (in ZF set-theory)?

Comment: Yes. The same goes for the other common categories Mariano mentions - there's no set of all groups, no set of all topological spaces, etc.

Answer (score 5):

(1) You mean $\operatorname{Nat}(F,G)$ and $\operatorname{Nat}(S,T)$...

Let $\mathcal C$ be the category whose objects are the sets and where for each pair of objects $x$, $y$ we have $\hom(x,y)=\emptyset$ if $x\neq y$ and $\hom(x,x)=\mathbb Z_2$, with composition given by addition. Let $I:\mathcal C\to\mathcal C$ be the identity functor.

Can you see what $\operatorname{Nat}(I,I)$ is?

(2) Non-small categories are all over the place: the category of sets, of vector spaces, of abelian groups, of topological spaces... There is absolutely no need to go look for them in exotic places like higher category theory!

Comment: thank you for the correction, that was a bad mistake. I will have a think about your question.

Comment: Hi Mariano, I am really not sure how to approach your question. If $\operatorname{hom}(x,y)=\emptyset$ for $x \ne y$, then we can't have the usual diagram for a natural transformation unless $x = y$, as the morphism $I(x) \to I(Y) = x \to y$ does not exist...